What is the title of this book about a female writer embroiled in a murder mystery?
I recently read a book and can’t remember the title or author. The plot included a female writer who had been in a car accident and kept having dreams about fire. She was living in New England for the summer with her husband, whose name was Guy. There was a caterer who was murdered by an ax. The murderer ended up being a woman named Sandra. Help!

This sounds like The Secrets You Keep, by Kate White.
From the description on Amazon:

Bryn Harper, an accomplished self-help author, already has plenty to deal with. She’s still recovering from a devastating car accident that has left her haunted by recurring, smoke-filled nightmares. Worse still, she can’t shake the ominous feeling her dreams contain a warning.
At the beginning of their relationship, Bryn’s husband Guy couldn’t have been more supportive. But after they move into a new house together, disturbing incidents occur and Guy grows evasive. Bryn is increasingly unsettled, and then a woman hired to cater their dinner party is brutally murdered.
As Bryn’s world unravels—and yet another woman in town is slain —she must summon her old strength to find answers and protect her own life. Her nightmares may in fact hold the key to unlocking the truth and unmasking the murderer.

